# Azure Release pipeline download multiple build artifacts as single zip

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Basically, is it possible with `Release Pipeline` to collect all the build artifacts configured for the pipeline and download them as single `.zip` file? I don't want them published to IIS or Azure. Just a button where I can download the build artifacts.

I've looked at `Download Pipeline Artifact` task but not sure if this will work for me.

Comment: Is the reply helpful? Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.  It depends how you are publishing your pipeline artifacts.  In the build process zip of the necessary files and publish like:

```
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    inputs:
      artifact: drop
      targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

This will then be availabe in the Pipeline run as a published artifact:

[image]

Afterwards your artifact will look like:

[image]

Of course either this would be added as a step or would need to extract as part of your YAML pipeline.